# Is it able to create simple shapes with just special fonts in html?

Tags: html, fonts

I don't know if it's the right place to post this question. If it's not the right place, please just delete it.

My question is if it's possible to create simple shapes like circle,rectangle,line,triangle etc by using some special fonts. Just like somebody did in [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org) which is using some special character sets to input the math formula in normal html.

Here is an article introducing [simple shape drawing in Latex](http://timmurphy.org/2010/08/20/drawing-pictures-in-latex/). I'm wondering if it's possible in html or markdown.

I'll appreciate if anybody can give me any hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, take a look to [this](http://icomoon.io/app/#/select) service, you can also create the custom-fonts in SVG format!

You can create your own fonts starting with characters from other fonts (also available from the service) or you can upload your single character or your custom font

As the [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) of Boostrap 3 !

Comment: Yes. This probably a workable solution. Thanks. But I prefer to the one I mentioned in my question (the way what Latex did) if possible.